Computing reverse conditional in Langevin Dynamics
I am doing some theoretical work in generative modelling with Langevin Dynamics, which is closely related to Diffusion Models.
We know the following stochastic process (called Langevin Dynamics), if simulated from $t = 0 \rightarrow \infty$, leads to samples from the distribution $\pi(x)$
$$
dx(t) = \nabla_x \log \pi(x) dt + \sqrt{2} dW
$$
$dW$ being brownian motion. Let $p(x(t))$ be the marginal distribution. My simple question is, how do I compute (what is the expression of) the reverse conditional distribution $p(x(t) | x(t+dt))$ ? Is it gaussian ?

Have you try Bayes' formula?

The reverse-time Langevin SDE is
$$dx(t)=\left[ \nabla_x \log \pi(x(t)) - 2\nabla_x \log p(x(t), t)\right]dt + \sqrt{2} d\bar{W}$$
by the result of Anderson (1982), where $\tilde{W}$ is the standard Wiener process with time flowing backwards.
The appropriate Euler-Maruyama discretisation of this SDE with a step from $t + \Delta t$ to $t$ is
$$x(t+\Delta t - \Delta t) = x(t+\Delta t) - \left[ \nabla_x \log \pi (x(t+\Delta t)) - 2\nabla_x \log p(x(t+\Delta t),  t+\Delta t)\right]\Delta t + \sqrt{2} \Delta\tilde{W}$$
where
$$\Delta \tilde{W} = \tilde{W}_{t+\Delta t - \Delta t} - \tilde{W}_{t+\Delta t} = W_{T-t} - W_{T-t-\Delta t} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Delta t)$$
So you indeed have a Gaussian reverse conditional distribution given by
$$x(t) | x(t+\Delta t) \sim \mathcal{N} \left(x(t+\Delta t) - \left[ \nabla_x \log \pi (x(t+\Delta t)) - 2\nabla_x \log p(x(t+\Delta t),  t+\Delta t)\right]\Delta t, 2\Delta t \right)$$

thank you very much. I kinda figured it out myself but glad I could verify from this :)
